# How do you persist data to disk from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, database, f#, persistence

I have a variety of rich data structures (primarily trees) that I would like to persist to disk, meaning I not only want to write them to disk but I want a guarantee that the data has been fully written and will survive a power-down.

Others seem to design ways to encode rich data structures in flat database tables as lookup tables from parent to child nodes. This facilitates running SQL queries against the data but I have no need for that: I just want to save and load my trees.

The obvious solution is to store everything as a blob in the data base: a single entry perhaps containing a long string. Is that an abuse of the database or a recommended practice? Another solution might be to use an XML database? Are there any alternatives to databases that I should be considering?

Finally, I'm doing this from F# so a turnkey solution for persisting data from .NET would be ideal...

**EDIT:** Please note that formatting (e.g. serialization) is irrelevant as I can trivially convert between formats with F#. This is about getting an acknowledgement that a write has been completed all the way down to the non-volatile store (i.e. the disk platter) and no part of the written data is still being held in volatile store (e.g. an RAM cache) so that I can continue safe in that knowledge (e.g. by deleting the old version of the data from disk).

Comment: Re "turnkey solution" - some (not all) F# constructs may be out of the *typical* window expected by many persistence layers - would using a DTO class layer (just prior to serialization) be acceptable if it simplifies things? Also - I suspect you might want to look at the *serialization* and *ACID* aspects separately.

Comment: If (looking at your comment to Reed) the serialization aspect isn't an issue, then perhaps any ACID *document* database.

Comment: @Marc: "ACID document database". Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: As a random suggestion; [Raven DB](http://ravendb.net/) might be worth a look

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of the constructors for .NET's FileStream class take a parameter of type [FileOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx). One of the values for FileOptions is *WriteThrough*, which "Indicates that the system should write through any intermediate cache and go directly to disk."

This should ensure that by the time your write operation (to a new file) returns, the data is committed to disk and you can safely delete the old file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was never aware of the existence of those fileoptions: WriteThrough, Asynchronous, RandomAccess, DeleteOnClose, SequentialScan, and Encrypted. Looking into each of them may deserve a good blog post.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done via [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx).

The .NET Framework includes many built-in options for serializing your data to disk, including using binary or XML-based formats.  Detailed [How-To articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172360.aspx) are provided in the MSDN Documentation.

Comment: XMLSerializer won't work with several F# types, notably records and discriminated unions, as these don't have default parameterless instance constructors. This is unfortunate, as discriminated unions provide an excellent way of modeling trees. Binary serialization is the most direct approach

Comment: @pblasucci: True - binary serialization (or a custom serializer) may be required if you're using F#

Comment: @Reed: How is this answer about formatting relevant to my question about guaranteeing persistence?

Comment: for F# records, please take a look at serializing using the DataContractSerializer classes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx your xml will not be as pretty, but the serialization will work

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Serialization is not about formatting - it is about persistence.  "Serialization is the process of converting the state of an object into a form that can be persisted or transported."  From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx

Comment: @Jon Harrop: You can serialize your object hierarchy with a DataContractSerializer and save the stream directly to disk, then reload it later... That's what Serialization is all about.

Comment: @Reed: I am well aware of what serialization is. My point is that it has absolutely nothing to do with this question about guaranteed persistence to disk. How do you "save the stream directly to disk" such that you *guarantee* consistence even in the event of a power outage partway through the save? Serialization has nothing to do with that, it is just a change of format.

Comment: @Jon Harrop, during power failures bad things can happen like hard disk can break, CPUs burning, memory failing, ... Do you really expect a software guaranteeing you that your data will be persisted even if your hardware breaks and there is nothing your software can run on? This is just science fiction you are asking here. I think @Reed answered your question perfectly fine. +1 to him.

Comment: @Darin: Hardware failures are also completely irrelevant. If I take Reed's advice and use naive serialization to disk then a shutdown halfway through a write would leave me with silently corrupted data. That is obviously useless to me. This is basic database functionality, not science fiction.

Comment: @Jon - I didn't take Reed's suggestion as implying "naive serialization to disk".  You can use .NET serialization to transform your data structures into either a byte array (using BinarySerializer) or XML (using DataContractSerializer).  You can then store this serialized data however you want (e.g. binary blobs in a database if the durability of the data is your primary concern).

Comment: @kvb: I can use any of a multitude of techniques to change the format of my data but it has nothing to do with assuring the consistency of its persistence to disk.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, you will require a resource which will allow you to engage in a [`Transaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.aspx) (more often than not, you would use a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

Most databases will participate in a `Transaction` if one is contained.  Disk operations can also be managed by a `Transaction`, but you would have to do some [specific work in order to utilize it in .NET](http://improve.dk/blog/2009/02/14/utilizing-transactional-ntfs-through-dotnet).

Also, note that this is only available on Windows Vista and later.

If you go the database route, then you could store the serialized contents of your trees in a blob (or text, depending on the serialization mechanism).

Note, you can also use the [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) functionality in SQL Server (2008 and up, I believe) to store your files on the filesystem **and** gain the benefits of transactions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) from F# before, but it's all about persisting CLR object graphs to disk in a transactional manner. If it works with records and discriminated unions, it might suit you.

Edit: I just tested db4o 8.0 (.NET 4 version) and it seems to handle both record types and discriminated union hierarchies perfectly well.

Answer (score -1):

Try using XMLSerializer (System.Xml.Serialization).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

It can automatically persist complex data structures based on their properties, and you can use attributes to control the output, if you wish:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx

Comment: XMLSerializer won't work with several F# types, notably records and discriminated unions, as these don't have default parameterless instance constructors. This is unfortunate, as discriminated unions provide an excellent way of modeling trees. Binary serialization is the most direct approach.

Comment: @C. Lawrence Wenham: How is this answer about formatting relevant to my question about guaranteed persistence to disk? Neither the XML serializer nor any other serializer makes such guarantees, AFAIK.

Comment: Nothing guarantees writing to the disk, you'll need to check afterwards that there were no exceptions, that the file exists and isn't zero bytes. You can implement System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification in a custom class that will enlist your write in a distributable transaction, though, which gives you a recourse to rollback other operations if the write fails

Comment: @C. Lawrence Whenham: The statement that nothing guarantees writing to the disk is somewhat incorrect.  Transactional NTFS has been around since Vista, so while yes, you can't guarantee a write to the disk, you can guarantee an atomic operation when interacting with the disk.

Comment: C. Lawrence Wenham: I'm talking about a guarantee that it has been done as an acknowledgement, not that it will be done. Checking file validity using APIs that also make no such guarantees obviously doesn't solve the problem: some of the data could still be in a volatile write buffer waiting to be written to the platter. Databases provide such data consistency assurances but I just need to persist a binary blob, not necessarily relational data.

Comment: @casperOne: But can Transactional NTFS guarantee that a write has been completed all the way down to the non-volatile store? AFAICT, it deals more with the atomicity of file-level operations (create, move, delete etc.)...

Answer (score -1):

Slightly OT as the OP didn't want XML, but seeing others mentioned the XML formatter...
If you want textual persistence, the SoapFormatter handles cases 
(cycles/object-graphs) that the default XML formatter does not - its XML is not as readable as XMLFormatter's, but it's more readable than binary :)